# Assert and Verify both fail

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Please see the code below:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    Moq.Mock<ISayGoodMorning> GoodMorningMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void init()
    {
        GoodMorningMock = new Moq.Mock<ISayGoodMorning>();
        GoodMorningMock.Setup(x => x.GoodMorning()).Returns(Test());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        GoodMorningMock.Verify(x => x.GoodMorning(), Times.Once());
        Assert.AreEqual(g.SayGreeting(), "Hola");           
    }

    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hola";
    }
}
```

The assert and the verify fail.  Why is that? Here is the code that is tested:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class SayGoodMorning : ISayGoodMorning
    {
        public string GoodMorning()
        {
            return "Good Morning";
        }
    }

    public interface ISayGoodMorning
    {
        string GoodMorning();
    }
}

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Greeting
    {
        public string SayGreeting()
        {
            ISayGoodMorning s = new SayGoodMorning();
            return s.GoodMorning();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to verify before you actually call the method, then you call a method that expects "Hola" when your test class uses "Good Morning".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the subject under test needs to be refactored to inject the dependency to allow a mock to be used when testing. Either via constructor or method injection. ([Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/))

This example uses constructor injection

```
namespace ClassLibrary2 {
    public class Greeting {
        private readonly ISayGoodMorning speaker;

        public Greeting(ISayGoodMorning speaker) {
            this.speaker = speaker;
        }

        public string SayGreeting() {
            return speaker.GoodMorning();
        }
    }
}
```

Next the test needs to be restructured so that the `Verify` is done after exercising the method under test;

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {
    Mock<ISayGoodMorning> GoodMorningMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void init() {
        //Arrange
        GoodMorningMock = new Mock<ISayGoodMorning>();
        GoodMorningMock.Setup(_ => _.GoodMorning()).Returns(Test());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        //Arrange cont'd
        var g = new ClassLibrary2.Greeting(GoodMorningMock.Object);
        var expected = "Hola";

        //Act
        var actual = g.SayGreeting();

        //Assert
        GoodMorningMock.Verify(_ => _.GoodMorning(), Times.Once());
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);  
    }

    public string Test() {
        return "Hola";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have to do this if you are mocking a WCF Service Reference?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The service reference should be abstracted behind a type you control so that it can be more flexible to maintain and test. Treat it as a 3rd party dependency.

Comment: Yes, there is: Service.svc and IService.svc by default.  The mock is not injected into the service though.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I am not entirely clear on what you mean. Ask a new question with an example in code that clearly explains what it is.

Comment: If you register the service interface with the IoC container then it should be able to be injected like any other dependency.